# Uncountable subcollection of open sets with nonempty intersection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given an uncountable collection of open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$, can we choose an uncountable subcollection which will have unempty intersection? I read that indeed, we could do that.

But on the other hand, I don't quite see why would this be impossible to have uncountably many open sets which all but for inifnitely many have an empty intersection. I know only countably many can be disjoint, but that doesn't mean that uncountably many are all NOT disjoint. It could happen there are these two in every subfamily of cardinality continuum that are disjoint, at least that's how I see it (bad intuition though).

Is there any constructive proof for this problem?

Comment: Any open set contains a rational. A countable union of countable sets is countable...

Comment: Yeah, as I wrote I know that.

Comment: I mean -- empty intersection of some amount of sets is not equivalent to all of them being disjoint, that's why I don't see where to use the fact you stated.

Comment: As you wrote? Somewhere else maybe - neither of those two assertions appears in your post. If you know both those things then you should see the simple proof that follows - what's the problem?

Comment: I'd explain if you had a better attitude - "Yeah, as I wrote I know that"? Good luck

Comment: Well, I'm sorry if you felt offended, it just appeard to me you did not read my question and posted an answer to a different problem (namely, that every family of disjoint open sets is countable). But if you say it simply follows this fact, then ok, I'll try to find the proof.

Comment: Lucky you, the completely trivial proof following the hint I gave has been posted. (Not I'm saying the person who posted the answer needed the hint for such a trivial thing...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{U} = \{A_\lambda \mid \lambda \in \Lambda\}$ be a collection of open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ where $\Lambda$ is uncountable.

For a rational $x\in \mathbb{Q}$, let $\mathcal{U}_x\subset \mathcal{U}$ be the set of sets appearing in $\mathcal{U}$ which contain $x$. Note that for every $A_\lambda\in\mathcal{U}$, there exists an $x$ such that $A_{\lambda}\in \mathcal{U}_x$ because every open set contains a rational number. Hence $\bigcup_{x\in\mathbb{Q}}\mathcal{U}_x = \mathcal{U}$.

Now, suppose every $\mathcal{U}_x$ was only countable, then $\mathcal{U}$ is a countable union of countable sets and so is itself countable. This is a contradiction and so there must exist some $x$ for which $\mathcal{U}_x$ is uncountable, and further by construction $x \in \bigcap\mathcal{U}_x$ so the set is non-empty.